# Firefox обрезает SVG

Tags: svg, firefox

Имеется фрагмент SVG, который в Chrome отображается правильно, но в Firefox(v 111.0.1) обрезается.
Обрезка SVG начинается примерно со значения 17900000 по оси Y.

```html
<svg 
  version="1.1" 
  baseProfile="full" 
  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" 
  viewBox="0 15019902 20055924 25139090" 
  width="100%" height="100%" >
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" id="104065155" d="M14226008,16019902 L10252803,17936553 L10248544,21235948 L10244875,21235766 L10241754,21235756 L10236489,21237226 L10230925,21240046 L10226857,21242841 L10222886,21246525 L10218741,21251520 L10216278,21254670 L10213917,21257943 L10211495,21261315 L10208439,21267352 L10207094,21270588 L10203245,21277516 L10200076,21283081 L10198137,21285732 L10194261,21290241 L10192114,21295034 L10189521,21301501 L10186083,21307522 L10184310,21312079 L10182589,21316316 L10180742,21323136 L10179818,21327408 L10178902,21328460 L10177867,21329742 L10177364,21331640 L10175062,21334353 L10167468,21342121 L10161097,21357010 L10154185,21376617 L10147379,21396937 L10142822,21415659 L10140321,21429132 L10137901,21442732 L10136232,21455291 L10134790,21467953 L10133707,21481166 L10134050,21487345 L10133982,21490049 L10134664,21493233 L10135951,21496055 L10138098,21499296 L10138272,21500922 L10137612,21502861 L10135560,21503669 L10134892,21505382 L10134344,21508781 L10133583,21511004 L10134023,21515266 L10134191,21519763 L10135239,21523720 L10137010,21527426 L10140096,21531702 L10142587,21535098 L10144984,21537486 L10145440,21539157 L10145298,21542878 L10144982,21544973 L10144477,21546511 L10144083,21548046 L10140827,21554303 L10138641,21560576 L10137421,21564111 L10135959,21567150 L10133302,21571358 L10130662,21576072 L10129008,21578498 L10124837,21584396 L10122229,21588377 L10119868,21591504 L10118140,21593483 L10115940,21594860 L10113884,21597076 L10110700,21600740 L10109617,21601907 L10107276,21604021 L10104866,21607319 L10102471,21611011 L10099713,21615561 L10098136,21618547 L10096866,21620733 L10095208,21623046 L10094269,21625052 L10092981,21628253 L10091839,21630828 L10090530,21631947 L10088657,21634550 L10087134,21637477 L10086788,21638710 L10042740,21614380 L10047347,21606303 L10049883,21601835 L10059672,21585075 L10067640,21573470 L10082063,21558026 L10087904,21549950 L10090295,21545768 L10088504,21541617 L10085002,21528971 L10084075,21518776 L10083581,21508939 L10084860,21499590 L10084566,21497949 L10083683,21482569 L10084914,21463866 L10088295,21436134 L10093620,21406524 L10099107,21383739 L10113900,21340372 L10121960,21321304 L10126918,21312794 L10133820,21304952 L10134286,21303233 L10139443,21289379 L10144355,21279677 L10148585,21269793 L10152009,21263423 L10158310,21255292 L10166840,21238721 L10173335,21228659 L10184371,21214570 L10193725,21205335 L10203690,21198061 L10217218,21191041 L10228289,21187557 L10236914,21185947 L10251016,21185965Z"></path>
</svg>
```

Не могу разобраться в чем проблема. Из того, что получилось найти, увы ничего не помогло. Прошу помочь в решении данного вопроса.

Скрин из Chrome
[image: Скрин фрагмента в Chrome]

Скрин из Firefox

[image: Скрин фрагмента в Firefox]

Comment: Покажите скриншотами в вопросе как у вас выглядит на разных браузерах

Comment: Что за дикие значения? О.о

Comment: Это фрагмент из большого SVG, где часть изображения отображается, а часть нет (в firefox).

Comment: небось в корел драв делали эту svg ?

Comment: надо весь svg видить, что там отображается по другому и где и для чего такие ужасные координаты

Comment: либо просто viewBox увеличте на миллион или больше

Answer (score 1):

Отредактируйте своё SVG, такие дикие значения не нужны.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" baseProfile="full" width="250" viewBox="0 0 5 6">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5 0 1.027 1.917l-.004 3.299h-.007l-.006.001-.005.003L1 5.223l-.004.004-.004.005-.003.003-.002.003-.002.003-.004.006v.004l-.005.007-.003.005-.002.003-.004.004-.002.005-.002.007-.004.006-.002.004-.001.004-.002.007-.001.005-.001.002v.002l-.003.002-.007.008-.007.015-.007.02-.007.02-.004.019-.003.013-.002.014-.002.012-.001.013-.001.013v.012l.002.003.002.003v.004H.91l-.001.003v.003l-.001.002V5.5l.001.004.002.004.003.004.003.003.002.003v.01l-.004.006-.002.007-.002.003-.001.003-.003.005-.002.004-.002.003-.004.005-.003.005-.002.003-.002.002-.002.001-.002.002-.003.004-.001.001-.003.002-.002.003-.003.004-.002.005-.002.003-.001.002-.002.002v.002l-.002.003-.001.003-.001.001-.002.003-.002.003-.044-.024.004-.008.003-.004.01-.017.008-.011.014-.016.006-.008.002-.004-.001-.004-.004-.013V5.5l-.001-.01v-.045l.004-.028.006-.03.005-.022.015-.043.008-.02.005-.008.007-.008v-.002l.005-.014.005-.01.005-.01.003-.005.006-.009.009-.016.006-.01.011-.014.01-.01.01-.007.013-.007.011-.003.009-.002h.014Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Хоть и не нужны, но Firefox всё равно должен уметь их нормально отрисовывать, наверное?

Comment: @andreymal, тут скорее всего проблема в самой реализации SVG в разных браузерах, как я понял из слов AlexandraTT, она в каждом браузере реализована по разному.